# What were the shortcomings of Robinson's resolution procedure?

Tags: logic, proof-assistants, automated-theorem-proving

Paulson et alii. *From LCF to Isabelle/HOL* say:

> Resolution for first-order logic, complete in principle but frequently disappointing in practice.

I think complete means they can proof any true formula in first-order logic correct. In the *Handbook of Automated Reasoning* I find:

> Resolution is a refutationally complete theorem proving method: a contradiction (i.e., the empty clause) can be deduced from any unsatisfiable set of clauses.

From Wikipedia:

> Attempting to prove a satisfiable first-order formula as unsatisfiable may result in a nonterminating computation

Why is that disappointing?

Comment: Suppose you run the procedure on a statement and it's still running after two weeks. What have you learned about the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "disappointing in practice" is certainly not definable formally, unlike "complete" (which does indeed mean "can eventually prove every true formula"), it's pretty easy to find examples where *naive* resolution is not even remotely adequate, i.e. examples which *should* be easy to prove but which resolution is extremely slow on.

A famous example is an encoding of the [pigeon hole principle](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.8736&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for $n$ holes in propositional logic (which is the statement "$n+1$ pigeons cannot fit in $n$ holes without duplicates). There is no proof of this statement using only resolution in time sub-exponential in $n$.

Things are even worse in predicate logic, where it is very easy to find statements without any fast resolution proofs.

Note that any implementation of resolution must implement a strategy for picking the resolvents, which is already a very difficult problem, and an active area of research, since most practical algorithms for theorem proving are *enhancements* of naive resolution, e.g. [hyper-resolution](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/%7Enguyen/aphr.pdf).